# Using 'Index-type' raster layers with negative values as independent variables in a multiple linear model in R

Tags: r, model

Using a multiple linear model I am trying to quantify the "effect" of abiotic landscape characteristics (slope, elevation, solar radiation, and a load of terrain indices) on vegetation greenness (NDVI) in a topographically heterogeneous landscape.

I have divided the landscape into three areas, extracted the rasters, and am using R to run three models (one per area).

Many of my x variables are indices ranging from negative to positive values, some -1 to 1, some, for example concavity/convexity ranges from -23.7262 to 24.0945.

Is it OK to use these as they are in the model?